# Matrices stored inside a dataset do not behave well

Tags: dataset

I am storing matrices in datasets as in

```
ds = Dataset[{
   <|"m" -> IdentityMatrix[2], "d" -> 2|>,
   <|"m" -> IdentityMatrix[3], "d" -> 3|>
   }]
```

These matrices are returned as Dataset[]'s by default, forcing me to use Normal each time I access them:

```
ds[1,"d"]          (* returns 2, correct *)
ds[1,"m"]          (* returns Dataset[List[List[...],...], not what I want *)
Normal @ ds[1,"m"] (* returns {{1, 0}, {... }}, correct but inconvenient *)
```

This is poor style. Is there a way to tell mathematica to treat these matrices the same way as other properties in the dataset?

A related issue is that the formatting of the matrices is ugly by default, because mathematica tries to interpret the matrix levels as sub-levels of the dataset.

[image: default formatting]

The only way to get these matrices to display decently is to use `ds[All, {"l" -> OutputForm}]` or `ds[All, {"l" -> MatrixForm}]` but this is again boilerplate code:

[image: custom formatting]

Has anyone tackled any of these issues?

Comment: "... do not behave well" is open to interpretation. Does it work as advertised in the docs? I think it is good style that the dataset functionality is not making any display/formatting decisions on my behalf.

Comment: This is not discussed in the documentation to the best of my knowledge. By "do not behave well" I mean that there is no bug strictly speaking, but the behavior appears undesirable/inconvenient. Dataset is definitely making a formatting decision on my behalf when formatting matrices as shown in the first image.

Comment: Near the end of the *Details and Options* section of  [`Dataset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html), the documentation says "When a query returns structured data (e.g. a list or association, or nested combinations of these), the result will be given in the form of *another Dataset object*", and that's the output you're seeing. The solution, as you've said, is to use `Normal`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @creidhne, I had missed this. I still find that this is poor design — I have Normal[]'s all over the place in my code.